# PHP: как наполнить массив значениями типа структура (объект)?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

В процессе изучения PHP дошел до задачи, которая показалась мне интересной. Хочу портировать часть своего кода с Delphi (Object Pascal) на PHP 7.2.2

В Delphi есть *записи* (record) с помощью которых можно определить структуру. Создав переменную типа *запись*, можно дальше создать типизированный массив из таких записей. Пример кода на Object Pascal:

```
type
  TEmployee = record
    Id: Integer;
    Name: string;
  end;

  TEmployees = array of TEmployee;

var
  E: TEmployee;
  A: TEmployees;
```

Дальше я запрашиваю данные из таблицы `SELECT Id, Name FROM Employees` и наполняю им `ADODB.Recordset`. Затем я инициализирую массив полученными значениями:

```
//динамически устанавливаю длину массива равную количеству записей в Recordset
SetLength(A, rs.RecordCount);

//пробегаю весь Recordset и инициализирую значения все элементы массива.
for i := 0 to rs.RecordCount-1 do
begin
  A[i].Id := rs.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger;
  A[i].Name := rs.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
  rs.Next;
end;
```

На выходе у меня получается массив из элементов типа `TEmployee`. Такой массив компактен и удобен для осуществления последующих операций с данными; к нему и элементам легко обращаться. Ну и можно сразу уничтожить `Recordset`.

Теперь перехожу к своим PHP-изысканиям:

В качестве аналога *записей* в PHP [предлагается использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323920/can-i-set-up-record-types-and-arrays-of-record-types-php) объекты. То есть моя структура будет выглядеть так:

```
class TEmployee {
  public $id;
  public $name;
}
```

Дальше я объявляю переменные и инициализирую `ADODB.Recordset` заранее сохраненными данными из XML-файла:

```
$e = new TEmployee();
$a = array(); //тут же я не могу указать тип, да?

$rs = new COM ("ADODB.Recordset") or die("Get a job loser.");
$rs->Open("employees.xml");
```

Ну и в заключительной части задачи я хочу "пробежать" по набору записей и поместить все значения в объект типа `TEmployee` чтобы добавить этот объект в конец массива  и, таким образом, наполнить последний:

```
$i = 0;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
  $e->id = $rs->Fields->Item(0); //правильно ли я устанавливаю значения?
  $e->name = $rs->Fields->Item(1);
  $a[$i] = $e; //правильно ли я инициализирую элемент массива?
  $i++;
  $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

А дальше, при выходе из `while` все мои переменные и сам массив оказываются пустыми. То есть `var_dump()` распечатывает массив с пустыми объектами и `print_r()` тоже ничего не показывает.

Интересно, что внутри `while` я могу напечатать `echo $e->name;` и увидеть значение, а после выхода из цикла все куда-то пропадает.

Пробовал `array_push($a, $e)` то тоже как-то безрадостно. Что я делаю не так?

> Примечание: я не хочу использовать PHP-массивы *с ключами*. Мне нужно чтобы сам PHP делал позицию первого элемента нулем. Так ведь можно? Пока мне сложно понять для чего вообще нужны массивы с ключами.

Comment: вы уж прям слово в слово не переписывайте. кому нужен этот COM в пхп? Если надо читать данные из XML, то для этого есть масса других способов.

Comment: в делфи кстати подход с записями в массиве тоже не шибко-то удобен

Comment: В реальном приложении я читаю данные из SQL Server. Чтобы постоянно не обращаться к сети, я "отцепил" рекордсет и в тестовом приложении подгружаю его их XML. Кроме ADO в PHP я пока еще не знаю что использовать. ADO неплохо мне служит со времён classic ASP. Ну а в Delphi использую FireDAC.

Comment: _в делфи кстати подход с записями в массиве тоже не шибко-то удобен_ я не буду спорить, но лично для меня ничего более удобнее и логичнее попросту нет ;-)

Comment: вы сейчас говорите о чисто виндовых технологиях, поэтому там и используется в т.ч. ADO. пхп же серверный кроссплатформенный язык. Если вы его изучаете, то посмотрите в документацию, там есть разделы и с работой с БД и с XML, есть и про кеширование данных. Не надо логику из настольного виндовз клиента полностью переносить в php.

Comment: Я изучаю PHP всего третий день. У меня все еще впереди :) PHP работает под IIS'ом, так что использую те технологии, которые удобны и хорошо себя зарекомендовали.

Comment: ADO в пхп это экзотика. Хорошо зарекомендовали себя PDO и sqlsrv. еще раз повторюсь, не стоит в пхп тянуть и пытаться реализовать что-либо из делфей. Чтение главы про PDO у вас займет 30 минут времени. Главы про SimpleXML не больше. Про сериализацию объектов и запись в файл и того меньше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79651/discussion-between-interface-unknown-and-teran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего TEmployee в PHP не нужен. У вас это класс, который вы преобразуете в массив. Можно сразу обойти $rs->Fields и занести данные в массив $a. Добавление в массив лучше делать без указания его индекса (это условие вашей задачи), поэтому нужно в цикле делать так:

```
$a[] = array(
    'id' => $rs->Fields->Item(0),
    'name' => $rs->Fields->Item(1)
);
```

На выходе вы получите многомерный массив:

```
0 => 
    id = 123
    name = Вася

1 => 
    id = 321
    name = Петя

и т.д.
```

В этом примере id и name обычные строки/числа, но могут быть и сложным типом, например массивом.

В отличие от Паскаля со строгой типизацией, PHP сам определяет тип переменной динамически, поэтому особого смысла его указывать при создании переменных нет. Вместо этого, наоборот, в PHP принято проверять нужный тип при получении/использовании переменной.

Comment: Потрясающе! И на самом деле, ведь просто как! Поправил свой код, но пока не знаю как из такого массива читать значения. Обращение вида `$a[$i]->id` (в цикле) почему-то выдаёт Notice. Надо использовать конструкцию foreach, да? Я её еще не изучал :)

Comment: Еще я догадался, что вот здесь `'id' => $rs->Fields->Item(0)` нужно явно приводить значения к определённому типу. Иначе массив распечатывается пустым. Поэтому сделал вот так: `'id' => (int) $rs->Fields->Item(0)`. Это нормальная практика в PHP?

Comment: Массивы (и объекты) лучше и проще обходить через foreach. Приводить тип — да, нормально, но в данном случае возникает неопределенность — вдруг это строка, тогда после (int) будет пусто или ноль. Я могу посоветовать для изучения внутренностей переменных использовать print_r() — тогда вы будете видеть что из чего состоит.

Comment: Долго не мог найти обращения к _конкретному полю_ (например, к name) определенного индекса массива, а потом по наитию догадался: `echo $a[0]['name']`. Ну и в цикле, соответственно `$a[$i]['name']`. Принимаю ваш пост как ответ на мой вопрос. Избежав преобразования объекта в массив, вы сделали решение задачи более изящным. Спасибо.

Comment: _>вдруг это строка..._ нет-нет, такого у меня не бывает :) Я точно знаю типы всех своих данных, а так же куда и когда они "заходят".

Answer (score 1):

Ну чуть чуть ясности внесу

```
$e = new TEmployee();
$a = array(); //тут же я не могу указать тип, да?
```

Да, можно.

```
$i = 0;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
  $e->id = $rs->Fields->Item(0); //правильно ли я устанавливаю значения?
  $e->name = $rs->Fields->Item(1);
  $a[$i] = $e; //правильно ли я инициализирую элемент массива?
  $i++;
  $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

У вас $e - это один класс элемент, получается что вы в $a[0], $a[1] и т.д. всегда записываете один и тот-же класс, а вам для каждого эл-та нужен свой отдельный класс.

Наглядно покажу, как правильнее:

```
$i = 0;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
  $a[$i] = new TEmployee();
  $a[$i]->id = $rs->Fields->Item(0);
  $a[$i]->name = $rs->Fields->Item(1);
  $i++;
  $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Скопировал код, но все равно на выходе пустой массив :( А еще вопрос: зачем в цикле постоянно создавать новый экземпляр класса `TEmployee`? Разве не проще перезаписывать одну единственную переменную этого класса новыми значениями?

Comment: Ну может проблема в вашем `$rs`я разбираться не буду, замените `$a[$i]->id = $rs->Fields->Item(0);` на `$a[$i]->id = $i;`. и хоть что-то увидите. Вторая часть вопроса: вы всегда присваиваете `$a[$i] = $e`, `$e` - это всегда один объект, один элемент. т.е у вас в цикле вы каждый раз изменяете значения у ОДНОГО объекта и его присваиваете в новую ячейку, у вас все ячейки указывают на ОДИН элемент. Если вам сложно представить, то представьте что в цикле `$e` - это ССЫЛКА на тот класс, который вы создали ранее, а он у вас один НО вы можете сделать так `$a[$i] = $e;` заменить на `$a[$i] = clone $e;`

Comment: Спасибо. Много прояснилось для меня. Я отлаживал `$rs->Fields->Item(0)` и понял, что там, по всей видимости, тип Variant, потому значения и не отображались. После `'id' => (int) $rs->Fields->Item(0)` все заработало. Ну и отдельно благодарю за `clone`. Теперь я знаю как инициализировать переменную значением, а не указателем.